# Indexing a sum of values by row from multiple columns

Tags: excel-formula, worksheet-function

I'm struggling with this one...

http://postimg.org/image/50itqsz2x/

I've added a link to a screenshot, because I can't post images here...

In row 2 i have week numbers up to week 9 in this example. Row 1 has a formula that determines to which month a week belongs. In this example, week 5 is in month 1 and week 6 in month 2.

I need to sum the values by weeks and categories and show them in another table as monthly values as given in the example.

Answer (score 0):

In B10 use this standard formula.

```
=SUMIFS(INDEX($B$3:$J$7,MATCH($A10,$A$3:$A$7, 0),),$B$1:$J$1,B$9)
```

Comment: It works, thank you very much! Can't vote up though :)